# In Vaadin 8, how can I activate an upload from a menu item, rather than an Upload button component?

Tags: vaadin8

I have an Upload component that uses a customer Receiver to upload and process a file.  I would now like to move that same functionality to a menu item rather than a button. How can I achieve this in Vaadin 8?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need an add-on for that, maybe something similar to [UploadButton](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/uploadbutton-add-on) or [UploadLinker](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/upload-linker).